# OutOfMemoryError while client streaming gRPC request

Tags: android, out-of-memory, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to upload a large file (165 MB) using client gRPC streaming.
The file is chunked into 2 MB chunks.

```
val channel = AndroidChannelBuilder
    .forAddress("server address", 443)
    .context(this)
    .intercept(GrpcAuthorizationInterceptor())
    .build()

val source = FileInputStream(File("/sdcard/Movies/Movie.mp4"))

FileServiceGrpc.newStub(channel)
    .uploadFile(object : ClientResponseObserver<UploadFileRequest, UploadFileResponse> {
        override fun beforeStart(requestStream: ClientCallStreamObserver<UploadFileRequest>) {
            var counter = 0
            requestStream.setOnReadyHandler {
                while (requestStream.isReady) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "sending ${counter++} chunk")
                    val bytes = ByteArray(2 * 1024 * 1024)
                    source.read(bytes)
                    val byteString = ByteString.copyFrom(bytes)
                    val request = UploadFileRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setData(byteString)
                        .setExtension(UploadFileRequest.Extension.MP4)
                        .build()
                    requestStream.onNext(request)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onNext(value: UploadFileResponse) {
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable) = throw t

        override fun onCompleted() {
        }
})
```

Each time I run this code, the application crashes with:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 125656 free bytes and 122KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592; failed due to fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 0 bytes)
```

Log output before the crash is as following:

```
sending 0 chunk
...
sending 61 chunk
```

What is important, there is no delay between each `sending x chunk` log entry, which means `setOnReadyHandler` is called immediately and `requestStream.isReady` flag stays `true`.

Seems like here is the problem: even though the previous data has not been sent and is buffered by gRPC, `isReady` returns `true`. The JavaDoc of `isReady` method says the following:

```
   * If {@code true}, indicates that the observer is capable of sending additional messages
   * without requiring excessive buffering internally. This value is just a suggestion and the
   * application is free to ignore it, however doing so may result in excessive buffering within the
   * observer.
```

Setting `android:largeHeap="true"` flag in `AndroidManifests.xml` solves the issue, however for me it seems like just a workaround.

How can I improve the code to get rid of `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: Dont load 2MB chuncks in memory, in that byte array. Just make a little buffer and fill in a loop that buffer with bytes read from the file. Then write those bytes out.